# Occurences of a number using streams in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, stream

I have an integer list containing some duplicate numbers.
How can I count the occurences of a specific number in that list using streams?

```
  List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();

        newList.add(3);
        newList.add(6);
        newList.add(6);
        newList.add(6);
        newList.add(4);
        newList.add(9);
        newList.add(0);
```

For instance, for the number 6 I would like to return 3.

Edit: I know how to do it using a traditional for loop, but I was wondering if there's a way using streams.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you know how to do it with a traditional loop? Us giving you the full solution will not really have a positive learning effect for you.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried anything yourself so far? Can you show us your attempt(s)?

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do it using a traditional loop. I just compare each element of the List with my element and then increment the variable that stores the occurences.

Comment: I tried using         long result = newList.stream().filter(integer -> integer == 6).count();

Comment: @classicmusiclover Well that looks fine and produces the correct result, doesn't it? What's wrong with that approach?

Comment: Using that approach it returns me 1, not 3.

Comment: Then you have an issue somewhere else, because the solution you provided in your comment is fine. Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `groupingBy` as shown below:

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = newList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
        System.out.println(map);
```

**Output:**

```
{0=1, 3=1, 4=1, 6=3, 9=1}
```

Then you can get the value of individual element as:

```
System.out.println(map.get(6));
```

Comment: It does indeed work, but is there a way to only display the occurences of a single number, and not all of them?

Comment: @classicmusiclover - The count of a specific number can be found from the `Map` as map.get(key).

Answer (score 1):

```
newList.stream()
    .filter(x->x==6)
    .count();
```

will give you number of occurrences for `6`.